# Stata: Change typeface of graph bar label

Tags: stata

I'm trying to use a different font in my graph and have managed to change the font almost throughout the graph. However, I don't find a solution to change it for the bar labels as they are not real "text".

My code so far is the following:

```
graph bar gccs ghs grs ges, blabel(bar, format(%9.2f)) ytitle({stSerif:mean of gender share of respective care work}) yline(50) ylabel(0 "{stSerif:0}" 50 "{stSerif:50}" 100 "{stSerif:100}") legend(label(1 {stSerif:Childcare}) label(2 {stSerif:Housework}) label(3 {stSerif:Reparations}) label(4 {stSerif:Errands})) bgcolor(white) graphregion(color(white)) bar(1, fcolor(olive_teal) blcolor(olive_teal)) bar(2, fcolor(lavender*.75) blcolor(lavender*.75)) bar(3, fcolor(64 105 166) blcolor(64 105 166)) bar(4, fcolor(251 162 127) blcolor(251 162 127))
```

Help is very much appreciated!

Comment: Hi and Welcome to Stack Overflow. In order to get a response it is helpful to include a small reproducible data example. That being said I think you want to add something like `graph set window fontface "Times New Roman"` before you create your bar graph. Moreover, once you do that the `stserif` prefixes in your labels will be redundant and you can instead have your labels in quotations. See ` help graph_set`

Comment: Hello @JR96, thank you so much this is exactly what I was searching for (and I just realize I actually have been very close to this during my search for the solution, argh haha). 
Thanks also for the hint with the data example, I will take that into account next time!

Comment: Excellent, glad your problem was solved!